# add soft-link to http svn repo?

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, http, symbolic-link

is it possible to add some kind of softlink to an svn repository?

i want to map the urls like this.

http://svn.server.com/repo/latest-stable -> http://svn.server.com/repo/tags/0.5.4-stable

Answer (score 1):

i now have created a new folder and added svn:externals property to the tag :D

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve this through an apache rewriterule -

Something like this in the server config file....

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/repo/latest-stable /repo/tags/0.5.4-stable
RewriteRule ^/repo/latest-stable/(.*) /repo/tags/0.5.4-stable/$1

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a symlink from the OS with ln.